# JSP to Thymeleaf logic & forward syntax equivalent

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

In trying to move from JSP to Thymeleaf- in the former a Spring Boot initial class (with the main method) performed some validation on a user logging in, and if valid would present a banner.jsp. On agreeing to the banner.jsp's statement the user would click the "Ok" (on the banner.jsp), which called an index.jsp that used 
`<c:if test='${empty Validated}'&gt;&lt;jsp:forward page="/do/Index" /&gt;&lt;/c:if>`.
 This ultimately brought up the webapp.

In converting to Thymeleaf I can get 
`<c:if test='${empty Validated}'&gt;&lt;jsp:forward page="/do/Index" /&gt;&lt;/c:if>` piece within the index (now .html). I'd figure something like

```
<div th:if="${empty Validated}" th:action="@{/do/Index}"></div>
```

might work, but it returns a 404 error. I'm wondering if I would , instead, need to call a controller. If that's the case I'm unsure of the syntax.

```
I've tried some syntax variations of the <div th:if="${empty Validated}" th:action="@{/do/Index}"></div> without success.
```

Index.html (as Thymeleaf)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--<c:if test='${empty Validated}'><jsp:forward page="/do/Index" /></c:if>-->
<div th:if="${empty Validated}" th:action="@{/do/Index}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would want the forward functionality to be successfully mimicked in Thymeleaf so that the index.html opens the webapp

Controller

```
package mil.dfas.springmvc.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * @author David Higgins
 */
@Controller
public class LMSSpringController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LMSSpringController.class);

    @Value("${messages.banner:default-value}")
    private String message = "HelWd";

    @RequestMapping("/banner")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        log.info("Config Example");
        System.out.println("LMS Controller");

        model.addAttribute("msg","Forward Handled");

        return "banner";
    }

/*    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String indexHandler() {
        System.out.println("index cont");
        return "forward:/do/Index";
    }*/

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView indexHandler(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("attribute", "index");
        System.out.println("index cont");
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/do/Index", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void handleRequest() {
        throw new RuntimeException("test exception");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller class? And is` Validated` is a parameter ?